# How to AutoIncrement after ENQ000000099 it should be ENQ000000100

Tags: sql, sql-server

**ENQ000000099 need output of ENQ000000100**

```
Alter function EnqID()
Returns char(12)
As 
Begin 

    Declare @lastval int
    declare @nextenqid nvarchar(30)

    Declare @count int

    set @count=(select count(enqid) from ENQ$Header)
      if @count <=0       
      begin
       set @nextenqid='enq00000001'
      end
      else
      begin
        set @lastval =(select max(cast(right(enqid,7) as int)) from ENQ$Header)
        if @lastval is null set  @lastval = 0000000
    set @nextenqid='ENQ' + Right('0000000' + convert(varchar(12),(@lastval + 1)),12 ) 
    end
    return @nextenqid 
    end
```

Comment: Whats not working about your code?

Comment: My int is 8 i need the increment value from right side after 99 it should increment 100 from the right inside

Comment: Aside - setting an integer to `0000000` is the same as `000000` or `00000000` or....`0`

Comment: its is 000000000

Comment: I would suggest you use a `SEQUENCE` and store your numerical part and prefix in separate columns; then you can use a computed column to store the concatenated value. The above will be very susceptible to race conditions.

Comment: Learn this lesson well. You don't need to (nor should you) count rows in a table to know if **at least one row exists**. That is simply inefficient code. The EXISTS clause has a real and useful purpose.

Comment: In addition, counting something can't yield a negative value; The query optimiser has had optimisations for some time that short-circuit a statment such as `if (select count(*) from table) > 0 then` but that wouldn't work in this case and SQL Server would obediently count all rows

Comment: @SAI you should [edit] the question and put clarifications in the question itself. Comments are not part of the Q&A. Make sure it is clear exactly what you are asking in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I have added comments. Please discuss if and query.

```
Alter function EnqID()
Returns char(12)
As 
Begin 
    Declare @lastval int
    Declare @nextenqid nvarchar(30)

    Declare @count int

    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(enqid) FROM ENQ$Header)
    If @count = 0
    Begin
        SET @nextenqid = 'ENQ00000001'
    End
    else
    Begin

        -- Here I have just changed 7 -> 9 right chr. 
        SET @lastval = (SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(enqid, 9) AS INT)) FROM ENQ$Header)

        -- I have changed the just below line, I used format function to achieved our desire requirement easily.
        SET @nextenqid = 'ENQ' + FORMAT(@lastval + 1, '000000000')
    End
    Return @nextenqid 
end
```

Comment: A good answer explains what was changed as well as providing working code.

Comment: OK, Thanks for your soft comment. I have added comments in the code for better understanding. Please comment to me if still have any queries.

Comment: Just FYI `//` is not a valid t-sql comment, use `/**/` or `--`

Comment: Yeah, I have just mixed it with .Net. Thanks, what do you think, is this task able to get Green Flag? :).

Comment: How would this handle race conditions?

Comment: Actually, we should use a separate table for IDs and update the IDs there with a Isolated Transaction with nanosecond wait. Try example -> create table def (nextcode int) 
insert into def values(1)

begin tran
declare @x int
update def set @x= nextcode, nextcode += 1
waitfor delay '00:00:00.010'
select @x
commit tran

select * from def

Comment: The above example is just an idea. you can discuss more if have any queries.